# Android skips fragment animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

In my application I have animation on fragment enter. But on several phones animation is sometimes (not always!) not played (eg. Samsung S5). Here is my code:

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right,
        R.anim.slide_out_left, android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
        android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

And my slide_in_right file:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

I've read that good idea is to use object animator, but when I'm using xml with object animator object, I'm getting error "unknown animation name: objectAnimator". Anyone could help?

Edit: xml with object animator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:propertyName="xFraction"
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
</set>
```

Comment: What does your Objectanimator XML look like?

Comment: @Kenneth I've added code to my question

Comment: objectAnimator is avaliable since Api22

Comment: FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();       
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_in_right);
    transaction.replace(R.id.content, myFragment);
    transaction.commit();

Comment: @Mayuri this is what i do ;)

Comment: @juanhl My minSdkVersion is 16, but my target is 22

Comment: You can't use it for versions lower than 22, minSdkVersion must be 22

Comment: @juanhl Ok, you have any other idea how fix this missing animation?